# How to embed a native window handler (HWND) into a C# WPF app

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winapi, pjsip

I'm working on an application for making video calls using pjsip.

I have:

1. The core library: A static library, which uses pjsua2, in C++.
2. A dynamic library for the C++/CLI bridge that wraps all the public interfaces from 1.
3. A WPF app, that links against 2.

The WPF app can open the capture device. Pjsip creates a sdl window for the video preview, and returns its HWND as a void* in the C++ side.

I am "casting" it into a std::string -- using std::stringstream stream operators -- and marshalling it to the WPF side.

I'd like to embed that window into my WPF main window. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes but WHY string?!

Comment: _"...I am "casting" it into a std::string..."_ what !!  An `HWND` is a `void *` but it's a pointer to nowhere.  It's just a convenient type to hold a value whose meaning is internal to MS-Windows, it does not represent a memory address.

Comment: I'm using djinni to make the bridge for other languages.. I cant send pointers in the generated interfaces... that's why I'm using std::string. On mac/swift I can do an unsafe cast to some cocoa class, and it's working fine.

Comment: I am also trying to do this now and I am not really sure how to proceed.  Do you remember what your solution was?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Hwnd​Host` class and host native windows in WPF.

`Hwnd​Host` is part of `System.Windows.Interop` WPF namespace.

Here is Microsoft example, but it is little tedious.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-win32-control-in-wpf